# change default folder names to the new language

Tags: home

i see double folders in home dir. one in english and one in greek my native language. english didnt get replaced?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If at the time of creating folders with names in you native language the old ones weren't empty then you will end up with both of them. As far as I remember there is an info about it in dialog asking about creating the ones in your native language.

Comment: Any ideas on how to make the english folders hide? oreven better replace?

Comment: Just remove the folders with english names. And don't forget to copy all your data before doing so.